# I can't get the dump_io module working

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, logging

To debug my webapp behaviour behind some weird network, I need to dump all HTTP request coming to the Apache2 server (on a standard Ubuntu). So I tryed to activate the **dump_io** module :

```
a2enmod dump_io
```

and I checked that the module was correctly loaded (after reload) by :

```
# apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep dumpio
dumpio_module (shared)
```

I added the following in the `<VirtualHost>` part of my site :

```
LogLevel debug
DumpIOInput On
```

Then `service apache2 restart` and `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

but nothing is showing...

I tryed putting the directive at global level (apache2.conf), putting all virtual hosts LogLevel to debug (as suggested in [Why can't I get Apache2 mod_dumpio working under Lucid Lynx Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/questions/168722/why-cant-i-get-apache2-mod-dumpio-working-under-lucid-lynx-ubuntu)) but no luck...

The only thing I'm getting related to my `setInfo` request is the following line (in error.log) which does not show if I set loglevel to warn, but shows event if I don't declare the DumpIOInput.

```
[Tue Nov 06 00:21:13 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 178.251.23.193] Zlib: Compressed 494 to 284 : URL /setInfo
```

So, what can I do next ? I'm pretty sure that I have incoming requests on my virtualhost, because I get the following error (which is the one I'm trying to clarify and debug) :

```
[Tue Nov 06 09:24:42 2012] [error] [client 178.251.23.138] no acceptable variant: /path/api/setInfo
```

Comment: ServerFault is officially empty... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1> To configure mod_dumpio you need to enable dump_io.**

```
$ sudo a2enmod dump_io
```

**2> in apache2.conf file write this line**

```
LogLevel dumpio:trace7
DumpIOInput On
DumpIOOutput On
```

**3) Then restart apache server**

Comment: Hum, many thanks. However, I just don't know why in the hell I asked this question, and why it was useful for me at the time. Well, it was in 2012 you know. :p

Comment: It does dumping logs to `error.log` file. But I can't find the log of POST-ed data. How can I enable it? I searched/googled it, I only found the old posts that don't work on my machine.